# Initializers may only be declared within a type / coder

Tags: swift

I use [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-from-scratch-with-swift-building-a-shopping-list-application-1--cms-25515) in order to create a simple Shopping List app. I have a problem with those lines of code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {   // error appears here
        self.init(coder: aDecoder);

        loadItems()
  }
}
```

There is an error: Initializers may only be declared within a type.
Why it is not correct? What should I change here?

Comment: Move the initialiser out of `viewDidLoad` – it belongs in the scope of a type, not a function.

Comment: That works, thank you! Please send it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initializers must be placed at the type level, not inside any other functions.

```
class Item: NSObject, NSCoding {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init(coder: aDecoder)
        loadItems()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // this code runs when the view loads
    }

    func loadItems() {
        // item loading code here
    }

}
```